# How do I verify a call is made on a specific list in my method?

Tags: java, unit-testing

If I have the following code:

```
public void process(List<String> messages){
    
    Map<String, List<String>> mapofLists = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList();
    List<String> list3 = new ArrayList();    

    for (String message : messages) {
        if(message.contains("123")){
            list.add(message);
        }
        else if(message.contains("456")) {
            list2.add(message);
        }
        else {
            list3.add(message);
        }
    }

    mapofLists.put("123",list1);
    mapofLists.put("345",list2);
    mapofLists.put("678",list3);

    service.makeApiCall(mapofLists);

}
```

I know how to verify the api call at the end.  But I am confused on how I can write a test to make sure each list (list1,list2,list3) has the right amount of messages added, based on the messages list passed in.  How would I do this?

Comment: Perhaps better catch the argument with the ArgumentCaptor that the service method was called with and check it.

Answer (score 2):

Mockito to my knowledge does not allow you to expose and mock the internals of a method like this. If you were passing the `mapOfLists` or the individual lists into the `process` method you would be able to do this fairly easily using the same or similar methods you used to verify the call to the service method; however, for this method that does not make much sense as the user would need to create each value before hand, and if you decide to change how many lists you need that would be troublesome down the road.

Probably the best way is to move the api call out of the `process` method, and return the `mapOfLists` to be sent using the service later. You can use your various asserts on the map to ensure the right data is being sent out.

This will also allow you to decouple the two actions so that processing and sending are truly 2 separate actions rather than 1 making your code more maintainable and readable.

```java
public class Processor {
    public static Map<String, List<String>> processor(List<String> message) {
        Map<String, List<String>> mapOfLists = new HashMap<>();

        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList();
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList();
        List<String> list3 = new ArrayList();    

        for (String message : messages) {
            if(message.contains("123")) {
                list.add(message);
            } else if(message.contains("456")) {
                list2.add(message);
            } else {
                list3.add(message);
            }
        }

        mapOfLists.put("123",list1);
        mapOfLists.put("345",list2);
        mapOfLists.put("678",list3);

        return mapOfLists;
    }
}
```

and in your test file

```java
public class TestProcessing {
    @Test
    public void testEmpty() {
        List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();

        Map<String, List<String>> expected = new HashMap<>();
        expected.put("123", new ArrayList<>();
        expected.put("345", new ArrayList<>();
        expected.put("678", new ArrayList<>();

        assertEquals(Processor.process(messages), expected);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didnt think of it like that!  So is there no way to sort of mock each list and verify the add call on each one?  I still like your solution!

Comment: Not that I know of. At least not without passing each list into the `process` method individually , but that will make adding lists to `mapOfLists` burdensome and hurt your maintainability. If there is a way to do this with Mockito I'd image it would be pretty convoluted and somewhat "hacky" anyway so best  to avoid if possible :)

Comment: See @Alex Rudenko's answer for a pure Mockito solution

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ArgumentCaptor` to intercept the argument of the API call, and then verify appropriate amounts of messages in the lists and/or the entire contents of the map, its key set and values as necessary.

Example test may look as shown below (not tested):

```java
@Mock
ApiService service; // mock makeApiCall

@InjectMocks
ProcessService processService; // implements process(List<String messages>)

@Test
void processOk() {
    ArgumentCaptor<Map<String, List<String>>> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Map.class);

    doNothing().when(service).makeApiCall(any());

    processService.process(List.of("123", "456_1", "456_2", "Test"));
    verify(service, times(1)).makeApiCall(captor.capture());

    Map<String, List<String>> map = captor.getValue();
    
    assertEquals(3, map.size());
    assertEquals(1, map.get("123"));
    assertEquals(2, map.get("345"));
    assertEquals(1, map.get("678"));
}
```